# Windows cmd batch file, copy source folder and contents

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

I'm using XCOPY to copy a deployment package filled with files. I can get them all to copy but I'd like them to retain in the folders. For example, I have:
C:\Utilities which has file1, file2, & file3. I use: 
**XCOPY "C:\Utilities\" D:\destination /s /i /w** 
and it copies file1, file2, & file3 no problem but I'd like it to copy the "Utilities" folder with the files inside. I searched for this but all answers I found are for copying only the contents of a source folder, not the source folder itself. Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you had was in fact successfully copying the files you wanted, then there's only one small tweak to make to your command.
You currently use a command that, yes, copies the directory structure and contents of the target folder, but doesn't copy the root. What you could do to fix this is simply *create the root folder in the destination*, like so:

```
XCOPY "C:\Utilities\" D:\destination\Utilities\ /s /i /w
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xcopy /E /I C:\Utilities D:\destination\Utilities
```

Update: Windows has a built-in manual for console commands. Try this:

```
xcopy /?
```

Comment: Can you explain the switches you used?

Comment: Every Windows console command has it own manual inside! Try executing "xcopy /?" and it will print explanations:
 /E          Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
 /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.

Comment: Very useful. Can you [edit] that into your answer? That will make it easier for future readers.